# JQuery - When I click the item but not change

Tags: jquery

Here is the site: http://whatshot.hk/

I did a little JQuery code, when I click the "fire", that will plus 1.

But don't know why, when I click the the fire of the end of the list, that never change immediately, but it work when I refresh.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // update good
    $(".fire").live('click', function (event) {

        var HOT = $(this).find(".fireNumber").attr("id");
        var addHOT = parseInt(HOT) + 1;
        var postID = $(this).attr("id");

        //$(this).find(".fireNumber").removeClass('fireNumber').addClass('fireNumbered');

        if (HOT) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "rating_process.php",
                data: {
                    rating: addHOT,
                    postID: postID
                },
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data['status'] == 1) {
                        $('#' + postID).find(".fireNumber").html(addHOT);
                    } else if (data['status'] == 3) {
                        alert("è«‹å…ˆç™»å…¥");
                    } else {
                        alert("error");
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            alert("error!");
        }

        return false;
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: Please post your relevant code here, in the question; otherwise, once your page is fixed, there's no context to your question which means it becomes nonsensical (at best) to future visitors with potentially the same problem. Please, [don't just link to your website](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), provide context for your question; help *us* to help *you* (and *others*)

Comment: Hi,Please post as not able to get you query And if you need to increment on click any value you need to replace incremented value data to id of that element

Comment: So, I have to go U.S and have to bring Pizza for you right ??

Comment: Sorry, I just added the code.

Comment: `event.preventDefault();` will never be called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, the function `.live()` is deprecated, if you are using jQuery 1.7+. You didn't update the `.html()` of the element.

```
$(".fire").on('click', function (event) {
    var HOT = $(this).find(".fireNumber").attr("id");
    $(this).find(".fireNumber").children(".fireNumber").html($(this).find(".fireNumber").html() + 1);
    var addHOT = parseInt(HOT) + 1;
    var postID = $(this).attr("id");
...
```